# Laravel - get DB result without table column name

Tags: laravel, laravel-4.2

I wanted to have the result with only the values not with the table column name in Laravel 4.2. For example,

```
$recs = DB::table('table_name')
        ->select('id', 'title')
        ->get();
```

the result is

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#863 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["title"]=>
    string(8) "my title"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#862 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["title"]=>
    string(10) "my title 2"
  }
}
```

but I want to have only the result NOT the column name, like

```
[
  2,
  "my title"
],
[
  3,
  "my title 2"
]
```

yes, I can make it by looping the result and make new array without column name. But is there are any way to get the result in this fashion using Laravel ?

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
$recs = DB::table('table_name')->pluck('id', 'title');
dd($recs->all());
```

Comment: Oh sorry, you need to append `all()`. Check my code again.

Comment: 'pluck' returning a number and so it is showing error when put 'all()' to a number

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-map) and the [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) methods:

```
$recs->map(function($i) {
    return array_values((array)$i);
})
```

I'm not sure about Laravel 4.2, but I've just tested it and it works perfectly in Laravel 5.3. If it doesn't work in 4.2, use the native [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function instead.

Comment: That is the only (nearly) correct answer for what I know. You'll just need to do `return array_values($i->toArray());` to make use of array_values. That being said I'm really interested in use case for this (converting human-readable keys into indexes).

Comment: @devk I've tested it too and since OP is using Query Builder here, `toArray()` will return an error. At least in 5.3 (not sure about 4.2 though). I've edited my code to cast objects to arrays. I've copied wrong code first. Thanks for mentioning that.

Answer (score 1):

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-flatten)

Try `$recs->flatten()->all()`

**Update**

Since your `$recs` looks like an array from your error. Try converting to `collection`. I hope this will work on v4.2

```
$recsCollection = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection($recs);
$recsCollection->flatten()->all();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply... im getting error since im using Laravel 4.2 and the given reference is in 5.4

Comment: getting error "Call to a member function flatten() on array"

Comment: "Call to undefined function collect()" i think 'collect' is not supported at 4.2

Comment: Updated the answer. `collect` helper function is not available in v4.2

Answer (score 1):

`DB::table('table_name')->all()->lists('id', 'title')->toArray()`

[Referance: Retrieving A List Of Column Values](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects)