# Pluck function with more than 2 parameters with Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello everyone i try to display more than 2 param with a **pluck** function query on **Eloquent** .

here my query :

```
$licence_entraineur = Licencies::where(['structure_id' => Auth::user()->structure->id])->where('type_licence_id' , '1')->pluck('lb_nom' , 'num_licence' , 'id');
```

I just get the `'lb_nom'` , i would like also `'num_licence'` , someone knows how to do this ?

Comment: Pluck function creates and array. A php array consists of `indexes` and `values`. If you use `->pluck(arg1)` the indexes will be ascending integers, values will be arg1 and if you use `->pluck(arg1, arg2)` the indexes will be arg2 and values will be arg1. You might want `->select(columns...)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an array to the `get()` method:

```
$licence_entraineur = Licencies::where(['structure_id' => Auth::user()->structure->id])
    ->where('type_licence_id', '1')
    ->get(['lb_nom', 'num_licence', 'id']);
```

Or use the `select()` method:

```
$licence_entraineur = Licencies::select('lb_nom', 'num_licence', 'id')
    ->where(['structure_id' => Auth::user()->structure->id])
    ->where('type_licence_id', '1')
    ->get();
```

If you want to [get `pluck()` like array without keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978115/laravel-get-db-result-without-table-column-name/42978387#42978387), you can use the `map()` method on a collection:

```
$licence_entraineur->map(function($i) {
    return array_values((array)$i);
});
```

**UPDATE**

In the comments you've said you want to get mixed result, so use this code (works in 5.4, doesn't work in 5.3):

```
$licence_entraineur = Licencies::select('lb_nom', 'num_licence', 'lb_prenom', 'id')
    ->where(['structure_id' => Auth::user()->structure->id])
    ->where('type_licence_id' , '1')
    ->get()
    ->mapWithKeys(function($i) {
        return [$i->id => $i->lb_nom.' - '.$i->num_licence.' - '.$i->lb_prenom];
    });
```

Also, you could use [an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) here. Something like:

```
public function getTitleAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->lb_nom.' - '.$this->num_licence.' - '.$this->lb_prenom;
}
```

And use it as `->pluck('title', 'id')`

Comment: thanks it's working ! in my select blade view i get the values as well . but i get the result like {"lb_nom : mourareau , "lb_prenom": mathieu .... there is a method to get only the values and not the column names ?

Comment: @MathieuMourareau yes, just chain the `map()` method as I've shown in 3rd part of my answer.

Comment: i tried the chain with your code but now i get Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::map()

Comment: but i steel have in my select box  {"lb_nom : mourareau , "lb_prenom": mathieu ....

Comment: my code is now : $licence_entraineur = Licencies::select('lb_nom' , 'num_licence' , 'id')
            ->where(['structure_id' => Auth::user()->structure->id])
            ->where('type_licence_id' , '1')
            ->map(function($i) {
                return array_values((array)$i);
            });

Comment: but i get Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::map()

Comment: You've forgot to use `get()`. Use the code from 1st or 2nd part of my answer and chain the code from 3rd part of the answer if you want to get just values. Like `....->get()->map(....`

Comment: like this .? $licence_entraineur = Licencies::where(['structure_id' => Auth::user()->structure->id])
            ->where('type_licence_id' , '1')
            ->get(['lb_nom' , 'num_licence' , 'id'])->map(function($i) {
                return array_values((array)$i);
            });      Now i have htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: it's a problem with my select blade . actually i have this : {!! Form::select('licence_entraineur_id', $licence_entraineur ,  null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Selectionnez un Entraineur']) !!}

Comment: @MathieuMourareau for the `Form::select()` you need to use `pluck()` with two parameters. It will create an array with `['2nd parameter' => '1st parameter']` data structure.

Comment: ok so i forget the code that you sended to me ? it need to be a pluck to use a blade select box right ?

Comment: @MathieuMourareau yes.

Comment: How i can do this with pluck ? sorry i'm lost ^^

Comment: @MathieuMourareau it depends on what `select` list you want to see. What do you want to use as keys? IDs I guess? And what do you want to make list option title (one item title) look like? `num_licence`?

Comment: I would like to have a list with 'lb_nom' , 'lb_prenom' , 'num_licence' and 'id' but i would like to see only the values in the select box not the columns of the database

Comment: @MathieuMourareau so, you want a list with 4 items? Or you want 4 lists?  Or you want one list where ID is the key and item title is something like 'lb_nom - lb_prenom - num_licence'? I'm sorry, but it's not clear.

Comment: I would like to get all the list of items in the select box with values item title like 'lb_nom - lb_prenom - num_licence' yes

Comment: for exemple if i click on the select box i would like to see Mourareau Mathieu 1458575 but not {"lb_nom : mourareau , "lb_prenom" : mathieu , "num_licence " : 1458575

Comment: @MathieuMourareau I've added the code which should work for you.