# Laravel fetch numeric?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How can I fetch an array of numeric arrays in Laravel?

---

Here's what I've got:

```
 $companies = Company::select(['id','name'])->get()->toArray();
```

This gives me back:

```
array:21 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "id" => 21
      "name" => "Cool Company"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      "id" => 4
      "name" => "Bacon Co"
    ]
    ....
```

But I want:

```
array:21 [
    0 => array:2 [
      21,
      "Cool Company"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      4,
      "Bacon Co"
    ]
    ....
```

Comment: a suggestion: 
$companies = Company::select(['id','name'])->get()->toArray()->map(function($item){
return array_flatten($item);
});

Comment: @user3681740 Don't think you can `->map` after it's an array, and I think I'd want `array_values` instead, but regardless, surely I shouldn't have to do that?

Comment: sure, sorry, you can use array_map instead, or put toArray() after map().

Comment: I'd like to know if this works for you: 
Company::select(['id','name'])->get()->map(function($item){ return array_flatten($item->toArray()); })->toArray();

Comment: @user3681740 Yeah, it does give the correct result, it's just a stupid number of function calls and iterations for something so simple -- something that PDO could have easily given me with `->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - get DB result without table column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978115/laravel-get-db-result-without-table-column-name)

Comment: @user3743266 Pretty sure they randomly changed what `pluck` does between 4.2 and 5.2, so that solution is no longer applicable. [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34405138/laravel-5-2-pluck-method-returns-array#comment60756426_34405138)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need this exact output you can do

```php
$companies = App\Company::pluck('name', 'id')
    ->map(function ($name, $id) { 
        return [$id, $name]; 
    })
    ->values()
    ->toArray();
```

Output:

```
=> [
     [
       4,
       "Bacon Co",
     ],
     [
       21,
       "Cool Company",
     ],
   ]
```

---

Not sure what you're doing with it afterwards but maybe just the output of `pluck()` will suffice

```php
$companies = App\Company::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
```

```
=> [
     4 => "Bacon Co",
     21 => "Cool Company",
   ]
```

Comment: No, I don't want it to be indexed. I'm serializing to JSON and I need an array, not an object. Your first solution will work I guess. Thanks